# Is Turn the Tide completely OP?

Tags: dnd-5e, paladin

As an Oath of the Crown paladin I have access to a bonus action called Turn the Tide, In summary:

> Turn the Tide. As a bonus action, you can bolster injured creatures with your Channel Divinity. Each creature of your choice
>   that can hear you within 30 feet of you regains hit points equal to
>   1d6 + your Charisma modifier (minimum of 1) if it has no more than
>   half of its hit points.

Me and my GM have discussed this through and really think this would be better off as a once per long rest ability. Otherwise it *feels* like it's going to be really difficult to kill us off during fairly balanced encounters.

My question is, does this scale well as a bonus action because you have to be fairly low HP anyway or is it better to run this as a long rest activity.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You've missed one thing. Turn the Tide uses your Channel Divinity, which you can only do once per short or long rest.

> When you use your Channel Divinity, you choose
>   which option to use. You must then finish a short or long
>   rest to use your Channel Divinity again.

Answer (score 14):

*Turn the Tide* is a use of the paladin's *Channel Divinity* ability, which specifies:

> When you use your Channel Divinity, you choose which option to use.
>   You must then finish a short or long rest to use your Channel Divinity
>   again.

You can only do it once in an encounter - it's not a permanent font of free hit points. It's also pretty minor healing at the end of the day.